# GLSL spot light. Inner spot light is not lit only the outer circle of the light

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a shader in GLSL and i have tried to create a spot light.

```
    vec3 s = normalize( vec3(positionOflight) - FragmentPosition );   
    float angle = acos( dot(-s,directionOflight) );   
    float Newcutoff = radians( clamp(cutoff, 0.0, 90.0 ) );     
    if( angle < Newcutoff )
```

This is the code used in the shader to test whether or not the fragment is inside the spotlights cone.In my code the `cutoff` is 20.0f. If the fragment is inside the cone it is red otherwise it is green.

[image: Rendered teapot]

Comment: The larger i set the `cut off` the thicker the red strip is.

Comment: I'm surprised that this shader compiles. You're using `cutoff` as part of the initializer expression when the variable `cutoff` is defined.

Comment: I changed the `cutoff` variable names and i still have the same problem.